# Bandwidth control on a router with WDS

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a tp-link router with WDS enabled to link with an old Cisco wag120n modem; I've noticed that with WDS the bandwidth control option has no effect. Is there any firmware which allows bandwidth control on the second router when it's in WDS mode?

Answer (score 1):

WDS(Wireless Distribution System) is a none standard Extension, Since all vendors have the option to implement it's own version. There will be too many variables to cover to assure unversally stable interoperability between routers using different chips. You might find some way to do this with QoS(Quality of Service) if the routers have chipsets of the same Manufacturer(broadcom for example), but between different Chipsets it is nearly impossible to keep track of all the different ways it gets implimented. So at this time no such firmware exists(if it ever will)

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that this function does not work on devices connected to the LAN cable router but it works with Wi-Fi adapters.

It seems that by LAN the device connects directly to the modem

[LAN To Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4KGP.jpg)

And by Wi-Fi it connects to the router, although it is strange because it does not appear in the DHCP list

[Wi-Fi To Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu5H6.jpg)

[DHCP List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjoYE.jpg)

These are the speeds by LAN without limit

[Test Speed LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb2zM.jpg)

And you're on Wi-Fi Limited to 2 Mbps
[Bandwidth Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKcV2.jpg)

[Test Speed Wi-Fi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlAbT.jpg)